# Making read and preview code work with multiple files input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have the images selected using the files input to appear under the input so that the user will have a visual cue about what he's going to upload. I've partially succeeded as my code does display the image, however, it displays only one image instead of all selected images.

I assume I'd need to use for loop and loop as many times as I have selected images in the input, however, I'm not sure how to get the amount of images into the select.

```
function displayInputImage(input) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var x = document.createElement("img");

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        x.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    x.className = "new-avatar-picture";
    $('.upload-btn-wrapper').append(x);
}

$(".upload-input").change(function(){
    displayInputImage(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file):

> The selected files' are returned by the element's HTMLInputElement.files property, which is a FileList object containing a list of File objects. The FileList behaves like an array, so **you can check its length property** to get the number of selected files.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the length without any examples on that website.

Comment: The documentation says that `HTMLInputElement.files` has a `length`. You already have `files`, you can see it in your code *`input.files`*, so look at its length: `input.files.length`.